# Remove add to cart on category product

Tags: layout, addtocart, magento2.3.1, category-view

I am trying to remove the add to cart and add to compare buttons from the category page. At present I have used the following code:

```
<referenceBlock name="product.info.addtocart" remove="true" />
<referenceBlock name="product.info.options.wrapper.bottom" display="false" />
```

In my `Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_category_view.xml` without any success

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to overwrite following template and remove addtocart content.

> vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/list.phtml

Because addtocart content is hard coded. Like:

```
<div class="actions-primary"<?= strpos($pos, $viewMode . '-primary') ? $position : '' ?>>
    <?php if ($_product->isSaleable()): ?>
        <?php $postParams = $block->getAddToCartPostParams($_product); ?>
        <form data-role="tocart-form" data-product-sku="<?= $block->escapeHtml($_product->getSku()) ?>" action="<?= /* @NoEscape */ $postParams['action'] ?>" method="post">
            <input type="hidden" name="product" value="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $postParams['data']['product'] ?>">
            <input type="hidden" name="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ Action::PARAM_NAME_URL_ENCODED ?>" value="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $postParams['data'][Action::PARAM_NAME_URL_ENCODED] ?>">
            <?= $block->getBlockHtml('formkey') ?>
            <button type="submit"
                    title="<?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Add to Cart')) ?>"
                    class="action tocart primary">
                <span><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Add to Cart') ?></span>
            </button>
        </form>
    <?php else: ?>
        <?php if ($_product->isAvailable()): ?>
            <div class="stock available"><span><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('In stock') ?></span></div>
        <?php else: ?>
            <div class="stock unavailable"><span><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Out of stock') ?></span></div>
        <?php endif; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
</div>
```

Or use css for hiding this block.

For addto block you can remove using xml.Ex:

> app/code/SR/MagentoCommunity/view/frontend/layout/catalog_category_view.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="2columns-left" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <referenceBlock name="category.product.addto" remove="true"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

Comment: the XML removed the compared/wishlist side of it, but not the button. Are you saying for the button the only way to remove it is to use CSS?

Comment: Yes, css or directly remove from phtml

Comment: Went the CSS route for now. Doesn’t feel right though. I would have thought it would be cleaner

Answer (score 0):

add to cart is more of a block so when you want to remove a block you must edit files related to that block like layout.xml file, .phtml file.